# Convertible types with variadic class templates

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Many times, I've used the `const` and `mutable` concept in C++ to create "const" or "mutable" types of objects, (similar to `iterator` vs `const_iterator`).  The point is to provide different types of "views" (const or mutable views) over other objects.  The general idea is that a mutable_object is convertible to a const_object, but a const_object is NOT convertible to a mutable_object, just like `iterator` vs. `const_iterator`.

This is very easy to achieve, by simply creating two types, and for the "const" type, you create a (non-explicit) constructor that takes a mutable type:

```
class mutable_object
{
    public:
    mutable_object() = default;
};

class const_object
{
    public:

    const_object() = default;
    const_object(const const_object&) = default;

    const_object(mutable_object m)
    { }
};

void function_that_takes_a_const_object(const_object)
{ }

void function_that_takes_a_mutable_object(mutable_object)
{ }

int main()
{
    const_object c;
    mutable_object m;
    function_that_takes_a_const_object(c);
    function_that_takes_a_const_object(m); // works

    function_that_takes_a_mutable_object(m);
    function_that_takes_a_mutable_object(c); // will fail
}
```

So, this is simple enough, and it nicely reproduces the C++ semantics of const vs. mutable types, like `const_iterator` vs `iterator`.

But, I tried to replicate this using class template types that take variadic template arguments, but can't get it to work:

```
template <class... T>
struct mutable_object
{ };

template <class... T>
struct const_object
{
    const_object(const const_object&) { }
    const_object(mutable_object<T...>) { }

    template <class... U>
    const_object(mutable_object<U...>) { }
};

template <class... T>
void FOO(const_object<T...> obj)
{ }

int main()
{
    mutable_object<bool,bool,int> m;
    FOO(m); // fails to compile
}
```

In this case, calling `FOO` with a `mutable_object<T...>` fails, with the compiler error:

```
test2.cpp:38:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘FOO(mutable_object<bool, bool, int>&)’
test2.cpp:38:7: note: candidate is:
test2.cpp:29:6: note: template<class ... T> void FOO(const_object<T ...>)
test2.cpp:29:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
test2.cpp:38:7: note:   ‘mutable_object<bool, bool, int>’ is not derived from ‘const_object<T ...>’
```

So, template argument substitution fails here.  I'm not exactly sure why, but I guess it has to do with the fact that more than one deduction would need to take place, first deducing the types for `T...`, and then finding a suitable conversion construction.

So, is there any way to write a conversion constructor for `mutable_object<T...> --> const_object<T...>` that will enable the compiler to properly bind a function call to `FOO`, where we pass `FOO` an instance of `mutable_object<T...>`?

Comment: Try adding a default constructor to `mutable_object`

Comment: Template argument deduction does not consider user-defined conversions.

Comment: @KerrekSB, but this would work with a single template parameter, like const_iterator<T> constructed from mutable_iterator<U>, no?

Comment: @Siler No, the types are simply unrelated. Template type deduction is a form of pattern matching, and the pattern `const_object<..>` simply does not match some `mutable_object<..>`. Type deduction does take inheritance into account. But this only works for types with pointer semantics, otherwise the inheritance violates LSP: A `const_object` cannot be modified, while a `mutable_object` cast to a `const_object` can be modified. This problem appears e.g. if you pass by reference.